# Script causes scene to load very slowly

Tags: unity, c#

So I have this script (pasting the entire thing in it's current state) :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using ooparts.dungen;
using UnityEngine.UI;


    public class RoomMapManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Map mapPrefap;
        private Map mapInstance;

        public int MapSizeX;
        public int MapSizeZ;
        public int MaxRooms;
        public int MinRoomSize;
        public int MaxRoomSize;
        public Image coverPanel;
        public int TileSizeFactor = 1;
        public static int TileSize;
        private UnityAction mapGenerationListener;
        private void Awake()
        {
            //  mapGenerationListener = new UnityAction(FadeCover);
        }
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            // EventManager.StartListening("GenerationComplete", mapGenerationListener);
        }
        private void OnDisable()
        {
            // EventManager.StopListening("GenerationComplete", mapGenerationListener);
        }
        void FadeCover()
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            coverPanel.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
            coverPanel.raycastTarget = false;
        }
        void Start()
        {
            //TileSize = TileSizeFactor;
            //BeginGame();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            {
                RestartGame();
            }
        }

        private void BeginGame()
        {
            mapInstance = Instantiate(mapPrefap);
            mapInstance.RoomCount = MaxRooms;
            mapInstance.MapSize = new IntVector2(MapSizeX, MapSizeZ);
            mapInstance.RoomSize.Min = MinRoomSize;
            mapInstance.RoomSize.Max = MaxRoomSize;
            TileSize = TileSizeFactor;
            //coverPanel.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1);
            //coverPanel.raycastTarget = false;
            //Time.timeScale = 0;
            mapInstance.Generate();
        }

        private void RestartGame()
        {
            EventManager.TriggerEvent("GameRestarted");
            StopAllCoroutines();
            for (int i = 0; i < mapInstance._rooms.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (GameObject g in mapInstance._rooms[i].Monsters)
                {
                    Destroy(g);
                }
            }
            Destroy(mapInstance.gameObject);

            //BeginGame();
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Prototype2");
        }
    }
```

Notice how Awake, OnEnable and Start do nothing. When this script is attachet as a component to a gameObject the scene where this gameObject is loads very slowly. I mean it takes like 30s to 1 min for it to load even in the editor. THe behaviour is the same when I build the project both to PC and Android. When I start the scene itself from the editor there is no delay. I have no idea what might be causing this.

Comment: If you deploy a build without the script, how long does it take? Same? Less? If it's the same, it's likely due to the resources already being loaded in the editor. The device has nothing pre-loaded, so you're seeing the full startup time. If it's less without the script, something else is going on, and we can keep looking at it.

Comment: If it is witout the script it is less ( about 1-2s). Uppon further investigation it seems to be connected to the prefabs that the script uses. I just draged them from the project folders into the public fields so It seems this causes the slow loading time. I have yet to test with Resources.Load instead of just draging them.